# How to make inline match and default arguments work together in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, inline, scala-macros, scala-3

I have the following, combining `inline match` and default argument:

```
inline def func(myArg: (Int | String) = 0) =
  inline myArg match
    case i: Int => ()
    case s: String => ()
```

It works fine when called so that the default value is not used:

```
// works fine
func(1)
```

However, when the value is used, it fails to compile:

```
// fails
func()
```

with

```
[error]     |cannot reduce inline match with
[error]     | scrutinee:  myArg$proxy1 : (myArg$proxy1 : (Int | String) @uncheckedVariance)
[error]     | patterns :  case i @ _:Int
[error]     |             case s @ _:String
```

Apparently the default value is a method that is not inlined. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Making `myArg` `inline` [works](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7Ow6qGD9Q52Eb6XEXcYXbQ), but I don't know how that changes the semantics of `func`.